# How to show result in datagridview?

Tags: c#

I have a stored procedure named `PSelectAllQuestion` that return questions.
i use linq to assign code below.

```
var allSelectedQuestion = glnq.PSelectAllQuestion(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue));
```

I  randomly select rows from `allSelectedQuestion` with this code:

```
var randomSelectedQuestion = allSelectedQuestion.Where(c => c.QuestionID == 4).Select(c=>c);
```

and assign it to dataGridView1

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = randomSelectedQuestion;
```

when i run the code `dataGridView1` shows nothing.what's the problem?

Comment: A perfect example of [XKCD Random](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: Use `ToList()` or `ToArray()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind your data into the data grid by doing the following:

```
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

That goes after you assign the data source.

Comment: How are you displaying the data grid after this? Can you show some code?